# How I can deploy superset on K8s using helm chart passing the superset_config.py values?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, apache-superset

I try use `helm install --name my-release stable/superset` to deploy the superset on Kubernetes. But, I need change the default config. in the [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/superset#configuration) this is not clear. Can someone help?

Comment: All of the values you list there can be injected using `helm install --set`, or written into a YAML file passed via `helm install -f`.  [Customizing the Chart Before Installing](https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#customizing-the-chart-before-installing) in the Helm documentation discusses this in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### helm fetch

You can use [helm fetch](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-fetch) to Download a chart to your local directory, so You can change the values in values.yaml file and then install it.

for example

```
helm fetch stable/superset --untar
```

Use text editor to change the values file

```
nano superset/values.yaml
```

Part of values.yaml is configFile, so as I can understand in link provided by You, you can change defaults here.

> configFile: |-
>
> #---------------------------------------------------------
>
> # Superset specific config
>
> #---------------------------------------------------------